# OS-independent app loading problem

Tags: applications, hardware, lineageos, operating-system

My phone has an odd problem, and I don't know where to start in diagnosing it. Several apps started having problems opening, taking a very long time (sometimes several minutes) to open; sometimes they won't open at all, and a reboot will be needed. Interestingly, once the app has been opened for the first time, it won't have problems again until the next reboot.

So I reinstalled the OS, and the new one is an entirely different version of Android. And yet, the problem was not solved! So I started thinking about a hardware problem (reading the disk? using memory?), but I wouldn't know how to diagnose what it is, and if it's solvable or not. Any hints are appreciated. I understand this will not be enough information to solve it, but I will answer questions.

The phone is a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with Lineage OS (unofficial, but the problem is present on two different, independently developed versions of the OS).

Comment: is it related to user-installed app or does it even happen on a fresh clean rom with default settings?

Comment: Which Android/LineageOS version so you use? On some versions the app is converted to native code (OAT/ART) when first run. May be there is a problem with the cache of the converted apps?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. @alecxs: it happens with many apps, including Gallery which comes with the OS. But I don't know what would happen if no apps were installed.

Comment: @robert: it initially happened with an old version of Android/Lineage; now I have Android 9 PIE and a recent release of Lineage.

Comment: can have various reasons, hardware issue, running out of RAM, maybe dalvik-cache is recreated each time, or maybe decrypting takes time, or just bad file system... best is try to analyze log files https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info